# How do I filter values in a Django form using ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to use the ModelForm to add my data.  It is working well, except that the ForeignKey dropdown list is showing all values and I only want it to display the values that a pertinent for the logged in user.

Here is my model for ExcludedDate, the record I want to add:

```
class ExcludedDate(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    recurring = models.ForeignKey(RecurringExclusion)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reason
```

Here is the model for the category, which is the table containing the relationship that I'd like to limit by user:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And finally, the form code:

```
class ExcludedDateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.ExcludedDate
        exclude = ('user', 'recurring',)
```

How do I get the form to display only the subset of categories where category.user equals the logged in user?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can customize your form in **init**

```
class ExcludedDateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ExcludedDate
        exclude = ('user', 'recurring',)
    def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(ExcludedDateForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['category'].queryset = models.Category.objects.filter(user=user)
```

And in views, when constructing your form, besides the standard form params, you'll specify also the current user:

```
form = ExcludedDateForm(user=request.user)
```

Comment: This worked "easy as pie!"  I appreciate not only your response, but the completeness of your answer.

Comment: So.... while the form now looks great, the change broke the view that adds the data.  Any ideas?  (code below)

Comment: def excluded_date_add(request):
    print(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        excluded_date = ExcludedDate(user=request.user)
        form = ExcludedDateForm(request.POST, instance=excluded_date)
        print("before if")
        print(request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("after if")
            excluded_date = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/excluded_dates/')
    else:
        form = ExcludedDateForm(user=request.user)
    return render_to_response('excluded_date_form.html', {'form': form})

Comment: @malandro95: When you are creating your form instance with request.POST, it appears that you're not passing in user.

Comment: don't forget to check out other answers, as there are often more than one way to do things that may work better for your particular situation.

Comment: How to do this for class based view?

Answer (score 1):

Here example:

**models.py**

```
class someData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="some value")

class testKey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="some value")
    tst = models.ForeignKey(someData)

class testForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = testKey
```

**views.py**

```
...
....
....
    mform = testForm()
    mform.fields["tst"] = models.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=someData.objects.filter(name__icontains="1"))
...
...
```

**Or u can try something like this:**

```
class testForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = testKey

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super (testForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['tst'].queryset = someData.objects.filter(name__icontains="1")
```

Comment: That will probably work but it's a bad practice. You shouldn't hack the form outside of the form class. It's much simpler to define this logic in __init__

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old; but its one of the first Google search results so I thought I would add how I found to do it.

```
class CustomModelFilter(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s %s" % (obj.column1, obj.column2)

class CustomForm(ModelForm):
    model_to_filter = CustomModelFilter(queryset=CustomModel.objects.filter(active=1))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomModel
        fields = ['model_to_filter', 'field1', 'field2']
```

Where 'model_to_filter' is a ForiegnKey of the "CustomModel" model

Why I like this method:
in the "CustomModelFilter" you can also change the default way that the Model object is displayed in the ChoiceField that is created, as I've done above.

Comment: Should you change column1 and column2?

Answer (score 0):

is the best answer:
BookDemoForm.base_fields['location'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control select2'}),queryset=Location.objects.filter(location_for__fuel=True))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31195900)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class based views based on models you can modify the queryset to filter the user. You can either do it in the view or write a mixin:

```py
class FilterByUserMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    """
    Filters the queryset with `self.request.user` in a specified `user_field` field. `user_field` defaults to "user".
    """
    user_field = "user"
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(**{self.user_field: self.request.user})
        )
```

Assuming a model like this:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    number_pages = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

You can have a `BookUpdateView` looking like this:

```py
class BookUpdateView(FilterByUserMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "book/my_book_update_template.html"
    fields = ["number_pages", "title"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("book-update-success")
    user_field = "author"
```

This UpdateView will ensure that the current user can only edit books he is an author of. We can't modify the `queryset` property directly because we don't have access to `request.user` yet.

Our custom `queryset` will be used in the `get_object` [method](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/5.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_object), which gets called in the `post` [method](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/5.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#post). If the object doesn't match Django will throw a 404 page.

You can add more filtering specific to the view by overwriting the `get_queryset` method and then calling `super`.