# How to create a filtered dropdown using Django forms?

Tags: python, django

I've got this model :

```
class QuestionInstance(models.Model):
    questionsSet = models.ForeignKey(QuestionsSet)
    question     = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    parent       =  models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
    optional     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'd like to create a dropdown, which user could choose one QuestionInstance.
It has to be filtered with questionsSet.

I've tested using a modelform like this, but it's not working :

(based on this [How do I filter values in a Django form using ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010489/how-do-i-filter-values-in-a-django-form-using-modelform/3013050))

```
class FormQuestionSelect(ModelForm):
    instanceList = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(questionInstance.id, questionInstance.question) for questionInstance in QuestionInstance.objects.all()])

    class Meta:
        model = QuestionInstance
        fields = ('instanceList', )
        widgets = {
            'instanceList': Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, questionsSet=None, **kwargs):
        super(FormQuestionSelect, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if questionsSet:
            #Tested many code here to filter, None of them worked :(
            #Is that possible to create instanceList there ?
```

I'm not sure using a modelform is a good idea for this kind of purpose.

A modelform is great when create or update a model instance.
When using specific forms, like in this case, I'm using a custom form in template :

View

```
questionInstanceList = QuestionInstance.objects.filter(questionsSet=questionsSet)
```

Template

```
<select name="questionInstanceSelect">
    {% for instance in questionInstanceList %}
        <option value="{{ instance.id }}">{{ instance.question.text }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and process them this way :

```
instanceList = request.POST.get('questionInstanceSelect')
```

I'm quite sure there's a proper way.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you out: [how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery)

Comment: how should your form behave after changing selection of `QuestionSet` by user without form submit?

Comment: You want the `Question`  foreignkey to be filtered based on selected `QuestionSet`. Am I correct?

Comment: @oleg I only want to display QuestionInstance list, filtrered by current QuestionSet (which is set from the view)

Comment: @arulmr thats correct

Answer (score 1):

You can change queryset of ModelChoiceField after form instantiation either in form `__init__` or in view. but this wouldn't solve issue on client side. When someone change `QuestionSet` `Question` selectbox will remain the same

To update queryset just update form field's one

```
form.fields['parent'].queryset = (QuestionInstance.objects
                                           .filter(questionsSet=questionsSet))
```

or if You change form `__init__`

```
self.fields['parent'].queryset = (QuestionInstance.objects
                                           .filter(questionsSet=questionsSet))
```

But One should remember that if `questionsSet` is changed on client side parent list will remain the same.

Would You consider to add client side code updating parent's choice list

Let me explain a bit.

You have model

```
class QuestionInstance(models.Model):
    questionsSet = models.ForeignKey(QuestionsSet)
    question     = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    parent       =  models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
    optional     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here parent field link to `self`(the same model).

Let us use `Model form for this model

```
class FormQuestionSelect(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuestionInstance
```

`ModelForm` will create fields for each model field with the same name
then after Its creation we update `ModelChoiceField` (created for `ForeignKey`) `queryset`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand correctly. But I don't need to refresh list after it has been instanciated.

Comment: does not work. Why are you using "parent" field ? the field created by the form is named questionInstance

Comment: please see my explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you want your field to be dynamic, you need to use jQuery and ajax for this functionality. I have given code for use in django admin. You can tweak it a bit, if you want to use it in custom pages. But the concept remains same for both.

#### question_set_change.js

```
(function($){   
    $(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id_questionsSet').bind('change', question_set_change);            
            $('#id_question > option').show();
            if ($('#id_questionsSet').val() != '') {
                var question_set_id = $('#id_questionsSet').val();
                $.ajax({
                "type"      : "GET",
              "url"         : "/product_change/?question_set_id="+question_set_id,
                "dataType"  : "json",
              "cache"       : false,
                "success"   : function(json) {
                    $('#id_question >option').remove();
                    for(var j = 0; j < json.length; j++){
                        $('#id_question').append($('<option></option>').val(json[j][0]).html(json[j][1]));
                    }
                }           
            });
            }
        });
    });  
})(django.jQuery);

// based on the questionsSet, questions will be loaded

var $ = django.jQuery.noConflict();

function question_set_change()
{
    var question_set_id = $('#id_questionsSet').val();
    $.ajax({
    "type"      : "GET",
  "url"         : "/product_change/?question_set_id="+question_set_id,
    "dataType"  : "json",
  "cache"       : false,
    "success"   : function(json) {
        $('#id_question > option').remove();
        for(var j = 0; j < json.length; j++){
            $('#id_question').append($('<option></option>').val(json[j][0]).html(json[j][1]));
        }
    }           
})(jQuery);
}
```

Include the following in views.py:

```
import simplejson
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse

from app.models import Question

def question_choices(request): 
    question_list = []
    question_set_id = request.GET.get('question_set_id')
    questions       = Question.objects.filter(question_set = question_set_id)    
    [question_list.append((each_question.pk,each_question.name)) for each_question in questions]
    json = simplejson.dumps(question_list)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

In urls.py:

```
from app.views import question_choices

urlpatterns = patterns(
    (r'^question_set_change/', question_choices),
)
```

In admin.py where you want to load question based on question_set:

```
class Media:
    js = ['/path/to/question_set_change.js',]
```

Comment: My dropdown is generated by the view. I don't need Ajax right now.