# Listing only usable values in OneToOneField Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to list only usable items in OneToOneField not all items, its not like filtering values in ChoiceField because we need to find out only values which can be used which is based on the principle that whether it has been used already or not.

I am having a model definition as following:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Bar(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo)
```

Now I am using a ModelForm to create forms based on Bar model as:

```
class BarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

Now the problem is in the form it shows list of all the Foo objects available in database in the ChoiceField using the select widget of HTML, since the field is OneToOneField django will force to single association of Bar object to Foo object, but since it shows all usable and unusable items in the list it becomes difficult to find out which values will be acceptable in the form and users are forced to use hit/trial method to find out the right option.

How can I change this behavior and list only those items in the field which can be used ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I filter values in a Django form using ModelForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010489/how-do-i-filter-values-in-a-django-form-using-modelform)

Comment: @Sayse its not a duplicate, because in here you need to filter on the basis on if that object has been used already or not; its OneToOneField not normal ChoiceField.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that? do you mean whether or not a `foo` already has a relation with a `bar`? that isn't any different, if there isn't a relationship then the `foo.bar` will be null

Comment: @Sayse Its different since its not ForeignKey relationship which is simple to filter its OneToOne relationship whose mapping is different and filter has to be done in some other way.

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old topic I came across it looking for the same answer.

### Specifically for the OP:

Adjust your BarForm so it looks like:

```
class BarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #only provide Foos that are not already linked to a Bar, plus the Foo that was already chosen for this Bar
        self.fields['foo'].queryset = Foo.objects.filter(Q(bar__isnull=True)|Q(bar=self.instance))
```

That should do the trick. You overwrite the init function so you can edit the foo field in the form, supplying it with a more specific queryset of available Foo's AND (rather important) the Foo that was already selected.

### For my own case

My original question was: **How to only display available Users on a OneToOne relation?**

The Actor model in my `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'peactor')
    # lots of other fields and some methods here
```

In my `admin.py` I have the following class:

```
class ActorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # some defines for list_display, actions etc here
    form = ActorForm
```

I was not using a special form before (just relying on the basic ModelForm that Django supplies by default for a ModelAdmin) but I needed it for the following fix to the problem.
So, finally, in my `forms.py` I have:

```
class ActorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #only provide users that are not already linked to an actor, plus the user that was already chosen for this Actor
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(Q(peactor__isnull=True)|Q(peactor=self.instance))
```

So here I make an ActorForm and overwrite the `__init__` method.

```
self.fields['user'].queryset =
```

Sets the queryset to be used by the user formfield. This formfield is a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) 
 by default for a OneToOneField (or ForeignKey) on a model.

```
Q(peactor__isnull=True)|Q(peactor=self.instance)
```

The Q is for [Q-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) that help with "complex" queries like an `or` statement.

So this query says: where peactor is not set OR where peactor is the same as was already selected for this actor

`peactor` being the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the Actor.
This way you only get the users that are available but also the one that is unavailable *because it is already linked to the object you're currently editing*.

I hope this helps someone with the same question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this in the **init**() method of your form.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(BarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # returns Bar(s) who are not in Foo(s).
    self.fields['foo'].queryset = Bar.objects.exclude(id__in=Foo.objects.all().values_list(
            'bar_id', flat=True))
```

PS: Code not tested.

Comment: got any errors? can you explain what problem you're encountering?