# Wagtail / Django - Listing only usable values in OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I'm trying to make a trick with my Wagtail models.

I have two models. The first one is a wagtail snippet, and the second one is a wagtail Page model. The page model has a OneToOneField who's referecing to my snippet model.

Simple example :

```
@register_snippet
class MySnippet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    # stuff


class MyPage(Page):
    snippet = models.OneToOneField(
        'MySnippet',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('snippet')
    ]
```

What I'm looking for is to only show available `MySnippet` values in the wagtail administration when creating a new `MyPage` page.

well, I'm just trying to hide unsusable ones.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [I tackled this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062273/8296763) on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078717/listing-only-usable-values-in-onetoonefield-django)

The use case is a bit different, but essentially we try to achieve the same thing: only show available (i.e. non-linked) items of the other end of the OneToOne relation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for the interface to show a single `select` from the values in MySnippet, you have to remove the quotes around `MySnippet` which are causing Django not to see it as a related model:

```
    snippet = models.OneToOneField(
        MySnippet,
        blank=True
    )
```

IIRC, you have to remove the `null=True` as well. Here's a full example, in case you didn't define `panels` in your snippet:

https://github.com/FlipperPA/wagtailpress/blob/master/wagtailpress/models.py#L29

Good luck!

Comment: Hello @flipper thanks for helping, my Page model works fine. I already have a `select` from the values in MySnippet, I'm just trying to hide those are already used in other pages. For example I have MySnippet A, B C, D and Pages 1 -> snippet A, 2 -> snippet B, 3 -> snippet C. Then, if I create the Page 4, I want to hide snippets A, B & C from the select. I don't know if it's possible without a hacky solution

Comment: Ah, just so you know, I read it like you were getting a text input field instead of a select of the values from the snippet. I'll noodle on that problem a bit, but you might have better luck asking in the Wagtail users Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wagtail