# Filtering query inside ForeignKey

Tags: django, wagtail

Let's say I have 100 players and 10 teams how can I remove any player from `FroreignKey` drop-down chooser that is already was chosen for another team?

inside `SpielerTeamRelationshipModel` I have `player = models.ForeignKey(Spieler)` and I would like it not to show players who have already been selected for another teams. Is this possible?

```
class Spieler(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    vorname = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('vorname', classname="col6"),
    ]

class SpielerTeamRelationshipModel(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Spieler)
    in_team_seit = models.DateField()
    page = ParentalKey('TeamRooster',
        related_name='spieler_in_team')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('player', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('in_team_seit', classname="col6")
    ]

class TeamRooster(Page):
    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        InlinePanel(
            'spieler_in_team', label="Spieler",
            panels=None)
    ]
```

One Player can be only in one Team. One Team can have one or more players. Very convenient for this is `InlinePanel`, but every time to choose one player from 100, it's excruciating.

Or maybe I'm not doing the right thing and there's a smarter way to solve this problem?

Comment: If each player can be only in one team, you can start with setting the player field on the relationship model as OneToOneField as you don't want multiple relationship records pointing to same player

Comment: @RamkishoreM thanks perhaps this is one of the right directions, but I understand that there is no way to filter out the choice. either Foreignkey or OneToOneField

Comment: I think you can use 'limit_choices_to'. Let me check it

Comment: Actually, you cannot check for lack of relation using 'limit_choices_to'.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078717/listing-only-usable-values-in-onetoonefield-django

Answer (score 1):

Strange but no one have mentioned [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together). It will help you to create unique relations between team and player.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
        unique_together = ("id", "team")
```

or sometimes you will need this

```
    class Meta:
        ...
        unique_together = ("name", "team")
```

Good luck!

Comment: interesting, in my case i have to make `class Meta:
        unique_together = ("player", "page")` right?

Comment: ok, thanks. I tried that, but i still get all `players` inside `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField`

Comment: @khashashin The idea is to simplify the logic. Further you can get all players with Player.objects.filter(team=Team)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a player as FK in team

You can solve the problem by having team  as FK in Player table

Comment: yeah but user can't manage `Spieler` model on django-admin side, he have rights only for `TeamRooster` that's why I have created `InlinePanel`