# Django form received wrong data from request.POST

Tags: python, django

I added a filter to my form, so that it only displays the options that belong to the user when request.GET, everything works fine at first, but next time it runs, something goes wrong. It shows the `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'id'` error, so by checking, I found that the `user` variable in the form received the data sent by `request.POST`. This should not happen, I guess? Here is my code

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request,_('success!'))
            return redirect('character-manage')
        else:
            messages.error(request,_('something is wrong.'))
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile,user=request.user)
    return render(request,'corp/profile.html',{
        'profile_form':profile_form
    })
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('pcharacter',)
    def __init__(self,user=None,**kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['pcharacter'].queryset = EveCharacter.objects.filter(bounduser=user)
```

When I add `print(user)` under the `__init__` function, refresh the form page and I will get a user object, but when I submit the form it will show something like this `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['*****'], 'pcharacter': ['2']}>`What went wrong? Any suggestions or guidance are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from this line.

```py
profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.profile)
```

You are passing `request.POST` as the first argument. This is then being interpreted the same as if you wrote this...

```py
profile_form = ProfileForm(user=request.POST,instance=request.user.profile)
```

The first positional argument in a `ModelForm` is `data`. That is why you can pass `request.POST` as a positional argument without writing `data=request.POST`.

To fix this you need to change your `__init__()` function to be operable with the `__init__()` function your form class is inheriting from.

I would recommend something like this...

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileForm,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    if 'user' in kwargs:
       self.fields['pcharacter'].queryset = EveCharacter.objects.filter(
           bounduser=kwargs.get('user')
       )
```

Comment: How to add data into kwargs? I changed the code as you said but there is no `user `parameter in kwargs, even I wrote `profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile,user=request.user)`under the GET method

Comment: You have to pass `user` in with `POST` to be able to access it when the form is posted. If you only pass in the user on a `GET` request `user` will be empty when the `POST` request is received.

Answer (score 0):

In the init() for form, if user, i am not sure what you are trying to achieve, i guess some logic is wrong. Can you try changing this and check again.

Comment: I copied from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013509/13624230) I guess this should prevent the execution of the following code when request.POST, but it dosen't do it's job now

Comment: Please don't post an Answer unless it actually answers the question. Once you have enough reputation use comments to ask for clarification or suggestions. Until then try to find answers you know the answer to or ask questions to increase your reputation.

Comment: @DanielMorell, Apologies i thought of helping him by showing where the issue might be. Will follow your suggestion from now on.