# Django Model advance Foreignkey Relation

Tags: django

I have a Django model which has relationship with user model. Where user are assigned to groups. especially "Admin", "Teacher","Student". So I want to make a foreign key relationship in such a way that it will show only The users that have been assigned to Teacher groups for Teacher_details model, And Similar for Student_Details Model. I have made the models Teacher_Details , Student_Details  and established foreign key relation with User model. But the problem is that its showing all the user when I am filling Student_Details or Teacher_Details. Hope you got my problem.
I am hoping positive response.

The code looks like this:

```
    class Student_Details(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(default='none', upload_to='img/')
        details_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        admission_date = models.DateField()
        previous_college = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        course_enrolled = models.ForeignKey(ModelUniversity,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        semester = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=semester,default=None)
            
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.first_name
    class Teacher_Details(models.Model):
        address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        image = models.ImageField(default='none', upload_to='img/')
        details_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        subject_taught = models.ManyToManyField(to='Student.stu_subject')
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.first_name
    
        def subject_teacher_teaches(self):
            return [str(s) for s in self.subject_taught.all()]
```

Comment: Are you using django-admin for insertion?

Comment: yes. i am using it.

Comment: You can use your own ModelForm in admin site [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)   Plus you can use filter in forms as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013509/5743382)

Answer (score 0):

Since both models have a user_id reference, you could use that info to search both models based on the request and fetch the necessary instance. Make a view which checks the user_id in the request, search both models and return the results (I assume a user cannot belong to both groups...)

Comment: no i am saying i just  want to show up only the teacher user  while inserting data for teacher details . So Is it possible while creating model?  or we should define it from admin.py for django-admin insertion.